# Make a negative lookahead case-insensitive

Tags: php, regex, pcre, case-insensitive, regex-lookarounds

I have the following expression:

```
$exp = "/^(?!.*?that).*$/";
```

which is meant to match any line that does not contain "that".

I have the following three sentences:

```
$str = array(   
   "I like this sentence.", #line1
   "I like that sentence.", #line2
   "I link THAT sentence."  #line3
);
```

The match is case-sensitive and therefore only lines 1 and 3 are matched. So far so good.

However, I would like to make it case-insensitive, so that it only matches line 1. I have tried with an inline modifier, i.e. "(?-i ... )":

```
$exp = "/^(?!.*?(?i:that)).*$/";
```

and as a flag, i.e. "/ ... /i":

```
$exp = "/^(?!.*?that).*$/i";
```

but to no avail.

I run the search with the following loop:

```
foreach($str as $s) {
    preg_match_all($exp, $s, $matches); 
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

with output:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'I like this sentence.' (length=21)
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'I link THAT sentence.' (length=21)
```

and an online demo is available here: https://regex101.com/r/bs9rzF/1

I would grateful for any tips about how I can make my regular expression case-insensitive.

**EDIT:** I was incorrectly using "?-i" instead of "?-i", as some contributors correctly point out. Fixed now.

Comment: `$exp = "/^(?!.*?that).*$/i";` is correct and should work. However `(?-i:...` switches off the i modifier. To switch it on: `(?i:...`

Comment: Your second try with `$exp = "/^(?!.*?that).*$/i";` [**should work.**](https://3v4l.org/sEXhn)

Comment: Indeed, it seems the problem that made the search case-sensitive regardless of the i modifier was somewhere else: the u flag is also needed for languages with accents and other alphabets, i.e. `"/^(?!.*?that).*$/ui"` Thanks for your quick answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first regex `^(?!.*?that).*$` has nothing to do with case sensitivity as you are not using any modifier for case insensitivity.

The regex matches first and third sentence because your regex is saying that there **shouldn't** be a word `that` (**case sensitive here**) in the sentence, which is true for first and third sentence (In third sentence you have **THAT** which is not same as **that**)

To match only the first sentence, you can use the inline modifier `(?i)` like

```
(?i)^(?!.*?that).*$
```

See **[`here`](https://regex101.com/r/M26y55/1)**

BTW, your `/^(?!.*?that).*$/i` regex is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
^(?!.*?(?i)that).*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/L21Fj5/1/). In your expression (`(?-i)`) you were turning the modifier **off**.